# xpath: how to get all rows from second table column?

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara

I have a table with multiple rows and columns.

How to find all rows from second column using xpath?

Comment: Good question, +1. @mu is too short has identified a problem with the currently accepted answer and it is good to know that adequate XPath expressions exist that avoid this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use**:

```
ExprToTheTable/tr/td[2] | ExprToTheTable/tbody/tr/td[2]
```

This selects any `td` child of either any `tr` or any `tbody` child of the `table`, identified by the expression `ExprToTheTable`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean all values from the second column?

```
    //table/tr/td[position()=2]
```

Comment: Good guess but there might be a `<tbody>` in the way.